# Heroku collect static manual

Tags: python, django, heroku

Is there a way that I can run collectstatic manually in my terminal and disable heroku from doing it automatically? I want to run

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

However, on Heroku, it defaults to

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

If I disable collectstatic on heroku, can someone give me steps to do it manually please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to turn it off, like this

`heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`

Then you deploy like usually

`git push heroku master`

Then you have to run migrations

`heroku run python3 manage.py migrate`

Now you run collectstatic using bower

`heroku run 'bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput'`

And then this is optional, this is how you turn them on again for future deploys

`heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`